# Cypress could not verify that this server is running when using Docker and Docker Compose

Tags: docker, testing, docker-compose, dockerfile, cypress

I currently have three docker containers running:

1. Docker container for the front-end web app (exposed on port 8080)
2. Docker container for the back-end server (exposed on port 5000)
3. Docker container for my MongoDB database.

All three containers are working perfectly and when I visit http://localhost:8080, I can interact with my web application with no issues.

I'm trying to set up a fourth Cypress container that will run my end to end tests for my app. Unfortunately, this Cypress container throws the below error, when it attempts to run my Cypress tests:

```
cypress | Cypress could not verify that this server is running:
cypress |
cypress |   > http://localhost:8080
cypress |
cypress | We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.
cypress |
cypress | Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.
cypress |
cypress | We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
cypress | We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
cypress | We will try connecting to it 1 more time...
cypress |
cypress | Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.
cypress |
cypress | Please start this server and then run Cypress again.
```

**First potential issue (which I've fixed)**

The first potential issue is described by this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934920/7489488), which is that when Cypress starts, my application is not ready to start responding to requests. However, in my Cypress Dockerfile, I'm currently sleeping for 10 seconds before I run my cypress command as shown below. These 10 seconds are more than adequate since I'm able to access my web app from the web browser before the `npm run cypress-run-chrome` command executes. I understand that the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Boot-your-server) has some fancier solutions for waiting on http://localhost:8080 but for now, I know for sure that my app is ready for Cypress to start executing tests.

```
ENTRYPOINT sleep 10; npm run cypress-run-chrome
```

**Second potential issue (which I've fixed)**

The second potential issue is described by this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56812435/7489488), which is that the Docker container's `/etc/hosts` file does not contain the following line. I've also rectified that issue and it doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

**Does anyone know why my Cypress Docker container can't seem to connect to my web app that I can reach from my web browser on http://localhost:8080?**

**Below is my Dockerfile for my Cypress container**

As mentioned by the [Cypress documentation about Docker](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/), the cypress/included image already has an existing entrypoint. Since I want to sleep for 10 seconds before running my own Cypress command specified in my package.json file, I've overridden ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile as shown below.

```
FROM cypress/included:3.4.1

COPY hosts /etc/

WORKDIR /e2e

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT sleep 10; npm run cypress-run-chrome
```

Below is the command within my package.json file that corresponds to `npm run cypress-run-chrome`.

```
"cypress-run-chrome": "NODE_ENV=test $(npm bin)/cypress run --config video=false --browser chrome",
```

**Below is my docker-compose.yml file that coordinates all 4 containers.**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
        container_name: web
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - .:/home/node/app
            - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
        depends_on:
            - server
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=testing
        networks:
            - app-network

    db:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/db/Dockerfile
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:     
            - dbdata:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        networks:
            - app-network

    server:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/server/Dockerfile
        container_name: server
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - .:/home/node/app
            - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
        networks:
            - app-network
        depends_on:
            - db
        command: ./wait-for.sh db:27017 -- nodemon -L server.js

    cypress:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: cypress
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - .:/e2e
        depends_on:
            - web
        networks:
            - app-network

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    dbdata:
    node_modules:
```

**Below is what my hosts file looks like which is copied into the Cypress Docker container.**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

**Below is what my cypress.json file looks like.**

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
  "integrationFolder": "cypress/integration",
  "fileServerFolder": "dist",
  "viewportWidth": 1200,
  "viewportHeight": 1000,
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "projectId": "3orb3g"
}
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker is always "this container".  You can use the names of the service blocks in the `docker-compose.yml` as hostnames; `http://web:8080`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yep, this was absolutely the problem. If you write up that as the solution I'm happy to accept it as the answer. I would imagine this question and solution would be helpful to other Docker newbies like myself.

Comment: THAT, i did not see this in the docs somewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localhost` in Docker is always "this container". Use the names of the service blocks in the docker-compose.yml as hostnames, i.e., http://web:8080

(Note that I copied David Maze's answer from the comments)

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I understood whats the issue but what is the solution to it? What to edit in the docker-compose.yml file so that the local host of cypress points to localhost of web.

Comment: @Chromeium -> Use the names of the service blocks in the docker-compose.yml as hostnames, i.e., http://web:8080

Comment: cypress container: environment:(newline) - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://web

Comment: Life saver, thank you! It took me days to find your answer, I wonder how it was hidden so well. I am thinking to go back to all the SO questions I reviewed and place a link to this...