# Cypress Docker container does not connect to running server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cypress, sh

[ EDIT: I am not deleting the question even if it could be a [duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709659/cypress-could-not-verify-that-this-server-is-running-when-using-docker-and-docke?noredirect=1&lq=1), because the original question might be harder to search. In case this were not advisable, please feel free to delete/close. ]

I have this docker-compose:

```
x-common-postgres-env:
  &common-postgres-env
    POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    POSTGRES_PORT: 5432

x-common-postgres:
  &common-postgres
  image: postgres:13.4
  hostname: postgres
  environment:
    << : *common-postgres-env
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "${POSTGRES_USER}", "-d", "${POSTGRES_DB}"]

x-common-django:
  &common-django
  build: .
  environment:
    &common-django-env
    << : *common-postgres-env
    DJANGO_SECRET: ${DJANGO_SECRET}
    ALLOWED_HOSTS: ".localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]"
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "http://localhost:8000"
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: "http://localhost:8000"
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "wget", "-qO", "/dev/null", "http://localhost:8000"]
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"


services:

  db:
    << : *common-postgres
    profiles:
      - prod
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  db-test:
    << : *common-postgres
    profiles:
      - test


  web:
    << : *common-django
    profiles:
      - prod
    command: pdm run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      << : *common-django-env
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
    volumes:
      - ./KJ_import:/code/KJ_import
      - ./docs:/code/docs
      - ./KJ-JS:/code/KJ-JS
      - ./static:/code/static
      - ./media:/code/media
      - ./templates:/code/templates
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  web-test:
    << : *common-django
    profiles:
      - test
    command: pdm run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      << : *common-django-env
      POSTGRES_HOST: db-test
    depends_on:
      db-test:
        condition: service_healthy

  cypress:
    # image: "cypress/included:9.2.0"
    profiles:
      - test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.cy
    # command: ["--browser", "chrome"]
    environment:
      CYPRESS_baseUrl: http://localhost:8000/
    working_dir: /code/KJ-JS
    volumes:
      - ./KJ-JS:/code/KJ-JS
      - ./media:/code/media
    depends_on:
      web-test:
        condition: service_healthy
```

This Dockerfile.cy

```
FROM cypress/included:9.2.0

# WORKDIR /code/KJ-JS
COPY system.conf /etc/dbus-1/system.conf
RUN chmod 644 /etc/dbus-1/system.conf

COPY entrypoint.cy.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.cy.sh"]
```

and this entrypoint.cy.sh to activate the Cypress tests:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "### Create DBus"

dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id

mkdir -p /var/run/dbus
dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address &

# Wait for the D-Bus system bus address to be available
while [ -f /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket ]; do
   sleep 1
done

# Check if the dbus-daemon process is running
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep dbus-daemon > /dev/null; then
   echo "### D-Bus daemon is running"
else
   echo "### D-Bus daemon is not running"
fi

# Check if the D-Bus configuration files are correctly configured
if [ -f /etc/dbus-1/system.conf ]; then
   echo "### D-Bus system configuration file is present"
else
   echo "### D-Bus system configuration file is missing"
fi

# Make sure that the /var/run/dbus directory exists and is writable by the dbus-daemon process
if [ -d /var/run/dbus ]; then
   if [ -w /var/run/dbus ]; then
      echo "### /var/run/dbus is writable by the dbus-daemon process"
   else
      echo "### /var/run/dbus is not writable by the dbus-daemon process"
   fi
else
   echo "### /var/run/dbus does not exist"
fi

# Remove the /var/run/dbus/pid file if it exists
if [ -f /var/run/dbus/pid ]; then
   rm -f /var/run/dbus/pid
   echo "### /var/run/dbus/pid file removed"
else
   echo "### /var/run/dbus/pid file does not exist"
fi

echo "### Bus active"

cd /code/KJ-JS
cypress run --headed --browser chrome
echo "### after cypress run"

exec "$@"
```

When I run the docker compose --profile test up, the db spins well, django gets up and running, but Cypress cannot seem to connect.

It complained of not having Dbus running, so I added it in the entrypoint shown above, and tested all of its components, yet the error message still comes up:

```
kj_import-web-test-1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
kj_import-web-test-1  | December 28, 2022 - 02:32:40
kj_import-web-test-1  | Django version 2.2.28, using settings 'KJ_import.settings'
kj_import-web-test-1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
kj_import-web-test-1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:32:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5776
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:32:42] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 9662
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:32:46] "GET /docs/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6551
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:32:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5776
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:33:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5776
kj_import-cypress-1   | ### Create DBus
kj_import-cypress-1   | ### D-Bus daemon is running
kj_import-cypress-1   | ### D-Bus system configuration file is present
kj_import-cypress-1   | ### /var/run/dbus is writable by the dbus-daemon process
kj_import-cypress-1   | ### /var/run/dbus/pid file does not exist
kj_import-cypress-1   | ### Bus active
kj_import-cypress-1   | unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket,guid=1181acd37ea51796e63af6a863ab9ccf
kj_import-cypress-1   | [26:1228/013304.773071:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Address does not contain a colon
kj_import-cypress-1   | [26:1228/013304.773122:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Address does not contain a colon
kj_import-cypress-1   | [213:1228/013304.794142:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is 
kj_import-cypress-1   | Cypress could not verify that this server is running:
kj_import-cypress-1   | 
kj_import-cypress-1   |   > http://localhost:8000/
kj_import-cypress-1   | 
kj_import-cypress-1   | We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.
kj_import-cypress-1   | 
kj_import-cypress-1   | Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.
kj_import-cypress-1   | 
kj_import-cypress-1   | We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
kj_import-cypress-1   | We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
kj_import-cypress-1   | We will try connecting to it 1 more time...
kj_import-cypress-1   | 
kj_import-cypress-1   | Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.
kj_import-cypress-1   | 
kj_import-cypress-1   | Please start this server and then run Cypress again.
kj_import-cypress-1   | ### after cypress run
kj_import-cypress-1 exited with code 0
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:33:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5776
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:34:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5776
kj_import-web-test-1  | [28/Dec/2022 02:34:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5776
```

Please note that the server is running fine. You can see it from the above log (GETs replied with 200, even before the Cypress container starts trying to connect) and I can access it from my local browser.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I finally found some info here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19299

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was probably pretty simple: `localhost` in a container refers only to the container itself, **not to the host**.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709659/cypress-could-not-verify-that-this-server-is-running-when-using-docker-and-docke?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-59120813) pointed me in the right direction.

So, in order to properly instruct Cypress to watch/test the service, the `url` (`CYPRESS_baseUrl` inside the `docker-compose.yml`) that needs to be passed in is in the format `http://[service-name]:[port]`, which in my case was `http://web-test:8000/`

Be aware that:

- also the Cypress tests need to be directed there, and most likely
- the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` will need to include the `service-name`

PS: There might have been also a second issue at play: in my search I found this [reported bug](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19299) and several comments pointed to the `cypress/included:9.2.0` image as potentially affected. I decided to move onto the `9.7.0`