# Cypress fails to verify the server is running

Tags: docker, cypress

I've noticed this is quite common issue when working with containerized Cypress.
I've found one topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959995/cypress-could-not-verify-that-the-server-set-as-your-baseurl-is-running/54934920#54934920) but resetting
settings isn't really a real solution. In some cases may be.

I'm using docker-compose to manage build of my containers:

```
...
other services
...

nginx:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - users
      - client

cypress:
    build:
      context: ./services/cypress
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - nginx
```

here's my cypress.json:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://172.17.0.1",
  "video": false
}
```

I know it's recommended to refer to service directly like this `"http://nginx"` but it never worked for me and referring to it by IP worked when I used non-containerized Cypress. Now I'm using Cypress in a container to make it consistent with all other services but Cypress is giving me a hard time. I'm not including volumes because so far I didn't see reason for including them. I don't need to persist any data at this point.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/base:10.18.0

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD cypress_dev /app

RUN npm i --save-dev cypress@4.9.0
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify
RUN ["npm", "run", "cypress:e2e"]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:e2e": "cypress run"
  }
}
```

I'd very much appreciated any guidance. Please do ask for more info if I haven't provided enough.

Comment: Does the server *ever* come up? If so, I like to use one of the options in the link you referenced. The wait-on module will continually poll to check that the URL is responding before executing the next command.